# Why does my for-loop terminate when I call my class?

Tags: python

Every time the program terminates when it runs the third time through this loop:

```
for component_ID in self.component_IDs:
    print component_ID
    fundamentals(component_ID)
```

This is my `fundamentals` class:

```
class fundamentals(download):

    def __init__(self, ID):
        self.browser = spynner.Browser()
        self.url = self.getURL(ID)
        self.browser.load(self.url)
        html = self.browser.html
        print "1"
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        print "2"
        self.count = self.get_count(soup)
        self.currency = self.get_currency(soup)
        self.fundamentals = self.get_fundamentals_pages(soup)
        self.write_fundamentals_to_db(id, self.currency, self.count, 
                                      self.fundamentals)
```

The program always stops when soup = Beautiful(Soup) is executed the 3rd time. **This doesn't depend on which `component_ID` is provided.**

`component_ID` has a length of 30 and when I start the loop at index 2 it also runs two times and stops at the 3rd run.

How does such strange behavior happen and how can I prevent it the next time?

**More info:**
Additionally the program just terminates without an error-message after printing `1` for the 3rd time. I am not sure what to do now.

When I only implement the `.close()`, but call the loop as above, it stops after going through the loop once. When I save the instance in the attribute `self.component_ID` the loop breaks after looping twice.

**EDIT:** I solved the previous version of this question by closing the `spynner.browser` and changing how the loop works. Instead of just calling the class I build a list and appended the instances to it.

Comment: What are you parsing?  Put a try: except: structure around BSsoup to try to see what is going on.  Also, if Bsoup won't parse what you are looking at then try lxml and use bsoup as a fallback.  I had to use lxml for speed and document structure fixing and only used Bsoup as a fallback and also to detect encoding.  I had to put lots of try: except: statements around these calls.

Comment: What puzzles me is, that the the script exits prematurely without giving some exception. Wouldn't Beautifulsoup return something at least?
I thougth that the problem may be my class fundamentals without saving appropriately. I changed `fundamentals(component_id)` into `self.component_ID = fundamentals(component_id)` and now the program  still exits in the third loop, but at another line. I really don't know where to start looking for a problem...

Comment: spynner is strange to say the least. in my case it segfaults on second `browser.load()`

Comment: Which urls are in component_IDs? If you are using a local test server please also provide the html

Comment: Since you legitimately answered your own question, you should post an answer and accept it just to get this off the "unanswered questions" list.

Comment: As a rule, don't do hard work in a constructor.  It's a very bad coding habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the spynner.browser and change the way the loop works. Instead of just calling the class, build a list and appended the instances to it.